# Firebase database storing into sqlite database with some properties unchanged

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase-realtime-database

Okay so my app database is completely stored on firebase, 
and my app updates its database every day.

What procedure i used to follow everytime during updating the data:

1. Drop the current sqlite table
2. Create the table again
3. Fill in the data

This used to work perfectly, imagine a row is deleted so as i drop the whole table and rewrite the whole thing, the deleted row also get technically deleted from the local sqlite,But now there is a slight change in the table, there is a column, say "viewed" which stores if the particular row data is viewed or not, "true" or "false" (String)

Now if i drop the data while updating, it'll lose this column properties.
Then i thought of using UPDATE in sqlite and update the data of the columns of each row, but then there might be instances when a particular column is no more in the firebase, but if i do this, it will remain in my local database. (I mean that data is not edited but deleted). So how can i overcome this ?

**Old Table :**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appdata_videos (id TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT, subcode TEXT)");
```

**New Table :**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appdata_videos (id TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT, subcode TEXT, viewed TEXT)");
```

P.S. I am using firebase single time listener as i need to update data only once daily.

**I used to run this function everytime i wanted to clear the database :**

```
public void clearDB()
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS subCodes");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subCodes (id TEXT, dbName TEXT, subName TEXT, tagline TEXT, pref INTEGER, hasInterviewQuestions TEXT, hasVideos TEXT, hasCodes TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appdata_codes");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appdata_codes (id TEXT, question TEXT, code TEXT, tag TEXT, subcode TEXT, imglink TEXT, xlink TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appdata_videos");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appdata_videos (id TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT, subcode TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appdata_interviewquestions");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appdata_interviewquestions (id TEXT, subcode TEXT, html TEXT)");
    }
```

Comment: when you drop and make a new table you will not have redundant data in the first place

Comment: but now i am changing the table column.. i have a new column whose data should be contained

Comment: dont drop the table, update the table then delete whatever rows are not updated.

Comment: how do i do that exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solution helps you,

step1: add a new column date to the new table

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appdata_videos (id TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT, subcode TEXT, viewed TEXT, date TEXT)");
```

step2:get ids from firebase and check if the ids exists in local database (loop through all the ids)
example:

```
if(isTheIdAvailableInLocalTable(idFromFirebase)){
//update the date column to todays date (dd-MM-yyyy)
}else{
//new entry so insert into local table with todays date (dd-MM-yyyy)
}
```

Step3:delete from local table where date not equal to tadays date.

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Thanks a lot. Now just help me with one thing. How to manage dates ? which class should i use to and how do i compare two dates

Comment: Date date = new Date();  
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  
    String strDate= formatter.format(date);

Comment: compare the string "strDate.equals("30-11-2018")";

Comment: this looks ok but it is not advised to depend on dates in a database operation. If somehow your users device has the date changed...a glitch a reset a prank I don't know...this will fail. Use the ids instead of dates to be safe.Update the rows if the ids exist else delete them.

Comment: is it possible to get global current data and not the device one, so even if the user changes the date, it wont affect, becuase what you're saying @PembaTamang is update only if id exists, but i want to add a new row also sometimes, then how is that possible ?

Comment: since we getting a date once in a day, there wont be any issue even if the date is wrong but we have to care of using same date object for updating and inserting in step2.

Comment: let me break down a senario where this logic fails. Say you have two rows with dates `03-12-18 => a` and `03-12-18 =>b`  so tomorrow new data comes in but the device date has not changed. Say item `b` has been deleted within the day and item `a` is now `aa`. By your logic `a` will be updated to `aa` but `b` will not be deleted as step 3 will fail. So old data remains. Quite unlikely to happen but it is possible. Just a precaution otherwise your logic is ok @bk7. Sorry that I said use a `uuid` I meant use the item id the `key` instead of the date.

Comment: okay now i get your point, thanks for your comment. The solution could be getting the Date from reliable external source, does firebase provide any method to the current date?

Comment: I don't think so...fb runs on pacific time even if it gives a date it may differ. IMO getting date from the network is not possible. So one can use the item key. I think that would be enough.

Comment: Hi since there is a issue if device date is not changed for two consecutive days as pointed by @Pemba Tamang,  Urivik Shah you can update all the rows of date column with some random string for example :"none" before step2 , then continue with step2 and step3, this should solve the problem.